# Higher order derivatives of Cauchy integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

An excerpt from my course notes in introductory complex analysis.

Given a curve $\Gamma$ in the complex plane and a continuous function $\varphi : \Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$, define its Cauchy integral to be
$$
f_\varphi : \mathbb{C} \setminus \Gamma \to \mathbb{C} : z \mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}d\zeta .
$$
My course notes claim that $f_\varphi$ is then smooth and that its $n$-th derivative is given by
$$
\frac{d^n}{dz^n} f_\varphi (z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n+1}}d\zeta .
$$
In the proof, it is shown that the above formula holds for $n = 1$, namely that
$$
\frac{d}{dz} f_\varphi (z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2}d\zeta
$$
and the proof concludes by saying that the general case follows easily by induction on $n$, without elaborating on this.

I tend to write out proofs whenever teachers write '... follows easily' or something similar. Most of the time, the result indeed does follow easily, but this time I'm stuck. How does the general case follow from the case $n = 1$?

Just to clarify: in my course notes, the above result is derived before the Cauchy integral theorem and formula, so neither of those should be used in the proof.

Comment: If you can use the dominated convergence theorem, you can just differentiate under the integral. If you can't use a theorem allowing differentiation under the integral, you may need to look at the difference quotients, which is a bit tedious, but not very difficult. What can you use?

Comment: Let's say it's okay if you can reduce it to theorems of real analysis or measure theory. This theorem is really at the beginning of the course notes and we haven't had any complex analysis before. Of course, elementary properties of complex integrals (like linearity) can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \geqslant 1$, consider the function

$$F_n(\zeta,z) = \frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^n}$$

defined on $\Gamma \times (\mathbb{C}\setminus \Gamma)$. This function is continuous, and it is holomorphic in $z$, in particular it is infinitely often real differentiable with respect to $x = \operatorname{Re} z$ and $y = \operatorname{Im} z$. At the beginning of the course it may not yet be known that holomorphic functions are infinitely often differentiable, but for the instance used here, $z \mapsto \frac{a}{(b-z)^n}$, this is easily checked.

For every $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \Gamma$, there is an $r > 0$ such that $D_{2r}(z) = \{ w\in \mathbb{C} : \lvert w-z\rvert < 2r\}$ does not intersect $\Gamma$, and thus the partial derivatives of $F_n$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ are uniformly bounded on $\Gamma \times \overline{D_r(z)}$, hence differentiation under the integral is legitimate, and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{\Gamma} F_n(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{\partial F_n}{\partial x}(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta,\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_{\Gamma} F_n(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{\partial F_n}{\partial y}(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta.$$

For the Wirtinger derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigr)$ and  $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigr)$ we thus obtain

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \int_{\Gamma} F_n(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{\partial F_n}{\partial \overline{z}} (\zeta,z)\,d\zeta = \int_{\Gamma} 0\,d\zeta = 0$$

and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_{\Gamma} F_n(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{\partial F_n}{\partial z}(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta = \int_{\Gamma} n\frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n+1}}\,d\zeta,$$

so $I_n(z) = \int_{\Gamma} F_n(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Gamma$ with $\frac{d}{dz} I_n(z) = n\cdot I_{n+1}(z)$, which shows that $f_{\varphi} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} I_1$ is infinitely often complex differentiable and the given formula

$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n} f_{\varphi}(z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma} \frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}\,d\zeta$$

holds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the proof is clear! I had hoped for a short argument as to why the general case follows easily from the case $n = 1$, but perhaps such an argument does not exist, contrary to what my course notes claim.

Comment: I'm not sure what the intention was. Maybe they meant it in the sense that it's essentially the same argument for all $n$. That is the case whether you differentiate under the integral (the justification is always the same) or look at the difference quotients (namely $$\frac{1}{z-z_0}\biggl(\frac{1}{(\zeta-z)^n} - \frac{1}{(\zeta-z_0)^n}\biggr)$$ converges uniformly to $\frac{n}{(\zeta-z_0)^{n+1}}$ on $\Gamma$ as $z\to z_0$). For the difference quotients, things get a bit more cumbersome for arbitrary $n$, but it's not too bad.

Comment: The proof in my course notes was the second one, that's why I was confused about generalizing to arbitrary $n$. Anyway, your proof is clear and helpful, and that's what matters in the end.

Comment: @DanielFischer Proof of the uniform convergence, I can't see it?

Comment: @Elliot Choose $r > 0$ so that $D_{2r}(z_0)$ doesn't intersect $\Gamma$, and always assume $\lvert z-z_0\rvert < r$. With $\alpha(t) = z_0 + t(z-z_0)$, for every holomorphic $f$ on $D_{2r}(z_0)$ we have $$f(z) - f(z_0) = \int_0^1 f'(\alpha(t))\cdot \alpha'(t)\,dt = (z - z_0)\int_0^1 f'(\alpha(t))\,dt = (z-z_0)f'(z_0) + (z-z_0)\int_0^1 f'(\alpha(t)) - f'(z_0)\,dt.$$ Doing the analogous for the integrand $f'(\alpha(t)) - f'(z_0)$, we obtain $$\lvert f(z) - f(z_0) - f'(z_0)(z - z_0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\lvert z - z_0\rvert^2 \cdot \max \{\lvert f''(\alpha(t))\rvert : t \in [0,1]\}.$$

Comment: For every $\zeta$ on the trace of $\Gamma$, apply that to $f(z) = \frac{1}{(\zeta-z)^n}$ and divide by $z - z_0$. Note that $\alpha(t)\in D_r(z_0)$ for $t\in [0,1]$, and so we have $\lvert \zeta-\alpha(t)\rvert \geqslant \lvert\zeta - z_0\rvert - \lvert\alpha(t) - z_0\rvert \geqslant 2r - r$ for all choices of $\zeta$ and $z$. This gives the bound $$\Biggl\lvert \frac{1}{z - z_0}\biggl(\frac{1}{(\zeta - z)^n} - \frac{1}{(\zeta - z_0)^n}\biggr) - \frac{n}{(\zeta - z_0)^{n+1}}\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{n(n+1)\lvert z-z_0\rvert}{2 r^{n+2}},$$ where the right hand side is independent of $\zeta$.